Exposing a Minikube nodeport in ethernet interface via iptables so it's visible to ther hosts in the network
For an enterprise project prototype I am using Minikube to test a complex on premise Hyperledger Fabric (HLF) network. I need to expose HLF (non http) services running on Minikube. I have already done it with Nodeports but as I am using Docker driver in my Minikube they can only be exposed in the bridge interface that Minikube binds to, so I can only access them from the host machine, not out side it.
I want some of those ports to be exposed in my ethernet. Is there a way using IPTables to do this? Let's say I have Minikube in the bridge interface IP 192.168.49.2 port 7051 and I want it that service be visible in eth0 IP 192.168.2.4 also on port 7051.
I use Bookworm Linux (Raspberry OS)
What would be the IP tables rules?
Note: I have red in other older entries that the problem is with the DOCKER rules already existing when using Minikube with docker driver. These are my current rules:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.49.2         tcp dpt:7051
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.49.2         tcp dpt:8443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.49.2         tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.49.2         tcp dpt:2376
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.49.2         tcp dpt:5000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.49.2         tcp dpt:32443

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Note: In order to expose port 7054 I have tried the following rules without success... What am I missing?
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br-e2ab4e35d9ed -p tcp --syn --dport 7054 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br-e2ab4e35d9ed -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br-e2ab4e35d9ed -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 7054 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.49.2

(I have confirmed that the port is listening and working in the minikube ip address, 192.168.49.2, in the bridge virtual interface created by docker/minikube: br-e2ab4e35d9ed)
